# Is there any way to add a child movieclip on nth frame of a parent movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There are two movieclips on stage

mc1 and mc2

mc1 right now has say  10 frames total.

mc2 needs to be added on say 3rd frame of mc1.

I used the following, but it adds the child movieclip on every frame, instead of 3rd only.

```
mc1.addFrameScript(3-1,frameFunction); 

mc1.play();

 function frameFunction():void 
 {
      mc1.addChild (mc2);    
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MovieClips only have a single display list, so once you add a child, it will remain there until you remove it. That being said, you can possibly accomplish what you are attempting by adding a second frame script on a later frame to remove the child from the display list:

```
mc1.addFrameScript(2, addClip); 
mc1.addFrameScript(6, removeClip); // you'll want to change this frame number 
mc1.play();

function addClip():void 
{
  mc1.addChild(mc2);    
}
function removeClip():void 
{
  mc1.removeChild(mc2);    
}
```